# Where do I ask DevOps-related questions?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

I am trying to avoid an opinionated question, but I was asking this myself for a very long time, as the DevOps subject is supposed to be midway between Stack Overflow and Server Fault.

My personal experience with these two communities is at the two different extremes, a lot of positive and helpful feedback on Stack Overflow, while Server Fault was...  of less use, to be politically correct.

Comment: ...that said, I've answered plenty of Chef questions here -- as long as it's more a question that's in the nuts and bolts of programming as opposed to a higher-level strategic/planning/best-practices thing, you'll probably be fine here on SO.

Comment: Why higher-level and planning would not be ok here? Agile practices are also discussed here. In fact I do not see any reason why not to discuss here most of the thigs, unless they are only sysadmin specific.

Comment: discussion of agile practices are off-topic here; those belong on Programmers SE, at http://programmers.stackexchange.com/. See the help center -- it's pretty clear about what is and isn't topical on SO.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy this specific question (where to ask?) is actually better on [Meta.SE](http://meta.stackexchange.com/) but will need more information about what the actual question is.

Comment: Discussions are off topic everywhere at Stack Exchange. Please don't suggest crossposting to sites that you are not actively involved in @CharlesDuffy. This question isn't appropriate at Progs either.

Comment: @Ampt, I didn't say it was. I was speaking to a *different* category of question that the OP here brought up as a hypothetical in a prior comment.

Comment: Related reading: **[Where do I post questions about Dev Ops?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/134306)**

Comment: @CharlesDuffy `discussion of agile practices are off-topic here; those belong on Programmers SE, at programmers.stackexchange.com.` is incorrect in every sense. Discussions, of any kind, are not on topic for **ANY** SE site, programmers included. Discussions do not fit into the Question/Answer format.

Comment: @Ampt, granted, "discussion" was a poor choice of words indeed.

Comment: A small exercise: try formulating a definition of what DevOps actually is. Lets see if people are on the same page about that to begin with. I am predicting a wide range of disagreement as a result of it given how new DevOps still is. Reading the wonderful book "the Phoenix Project" already flipped my understanding of it 100%.

Comment: There's a proposal for it on Area 51: http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/85819/devops

Comment: @CharlesDuffy If the comment was wrong, can you delete?

Comment: @Yakk, if the option were available, I'd gladly edit it to replace the offending word with "questions" (which bears the meaning I had in mind at the time). Since the edit window has long since passed, and I stand by it other than that wording choice, I'd rather leave it in place until there's a larger, moderator-driven cleanup.

Comment: I find that as a devops myself I have accounts on many SE sites and ask questions on SO and server fault as the part of devops calls for one or the other

Comment: @CharlesDuffy My [personal experience DevOps is also not good](http://stackoverflow.com/q/34917093/2404470)

Comment: That's because that's not a very good question for Stack Overflow, not because it's to do with devops.

Comment: @Sobrique I'm not a DevOps zen, beginners come to SO so that they can get guidance from experts. Anyways, [I'll update the question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34917093/how-to-explain-chef-to-a-programming-student#comment57574120_34917093)

Comment: @student the question is now gone; I hope you start to realize that stackoverflow is not for getting "guidance", which is just another way of saying that you came here to be tutored. Give the help center topics a read to get more of a feel for what SO -is- about. http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Comment: @Gimby I do agree with you.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

DevOps questions are welcome on Stack Overflow so long as they follow the guidelines in the help center: They should be specific, answerable, not likely to result in a debate with more heat than light, and ideally centered in the nuts and bolts of programming.

Answer (score 2):

The goal of the (revived and presently making good progress) Area 51 DevOps Proposal is to provide a home for many of the questions not meeting the accepted answer criteria:

[image: Check out the Area 51 DevOps Proposal!]